# Displaying different data through portrait/landscape view

Tags: javascript, html, css, device-orientation

Is there a way of handling when the user turns from portrait to landscape view on a web application? Like when you are looking the web app on portrait view and you see the normal data.
[image: Stocks App on iOS, portrait view]

And then when you turn your device to landscape view you get to see some different data.
[image: Stocks App on iOS, landscape view]

My question: is there a way of accomplishing this with pure JavaScript and CSS? Or do I have to rely on a API?

UPDATE:
I found a way of doing it with pure/plain JS using the [Device Orientation API](http://mobiforge.mobi/design-development/html5-mobile-web-device-orientation-events) and I've found an example which accomplishes what I'm trying to do but I can't make it work properly because the if statement is interrupting me every time the rotation is greater than 90 and even if I put a variable to check if the rotation is already 90.

```
function init() {
        var compass = document.getElementById('compass'),
        comp = document.getElementById("comp");
        if(window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {

          window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(event) {
                var alpha;
                //Check for iOS property
                if(event.webkitCompassHeading) {
                  alpha = event.webkitCompassHeading;
                  //Rotation is reversed for iOS
                  compass.style.WebkitTransform = 'rotate(-' + alpha + 'deg)';
                }
                //non iOS
                else {
                  alpha = event.alpha;
                  webkitAlpha = alpha;
                  if(!window.chrome) {
                    //Assume Android stock (this is crude, but good enough for our example) and apply offset
                    webkitAlpha = alpha-270;
                  }
                }

                compass.style.Transform = 'rotate(' + alpha + 'deg)';

//THIS IS THE PART I'VE ADDED
var iftrue = false;
comp.innerHTML = alpha + "deg";
if (alpha >= 90 && alpha <= 100) {
    if (!iftrue) {
        alert("it is");
        return iftrue = true;
    };
}
else if (alpha <= 90) {console.log("it is not");
};
//TILL HERE                    compass.style.WebkitTransform = 'rotate('+ webkitAlpha + 'deg)';
                //Rotation is reversed for FF
                compass.style.MozTransform = 'rotate(-' + alpha + 'deg)'; 
              }, false);
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CSS Media Queries to detect, if a device is in landscape- or portrait. With your CSS you can define which information to show when. For example:

```
/* ----------- iPhone 6+ ----------- */
/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
 and (min-device-width: 414px) 
 and (max-device-width: 736px) 
 and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) { 
/* Your styles */
}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
 and (min-device-width: 414px) 
 and (max-device-width: 736px) 
 and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
 and (orientation: portrait) { 
 /* Your styles */
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
 and (min-device-width: 414px) 
 and (max-device-width: 736px) 
 and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
 and (orientation: landscape) { 
 /* Your styles */
}
```

See https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/ for more examples.

Comment: Jesus, that looks cool but it's a lot of work too, I'll play with that and see what I get. Thanks mate :')

Answer (score 0):

If using Twitter Bootstrap you could do something like this:

Text hidden on phone

Text visible on small devices

Please check out [Twitter Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) for more info:

Comment: Sorry but this is not what I am looking for. I was asking if there is a way of handling when the device orientation is changed from portrait to landscape view.